# Attempt to have ResultSet from a CONSTRUCT query Exception

Tags: java, semantics, sparql, jena

i am attempting to use the following query:

```
QUERY="PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> \n" +
            " PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> \n" +
                    "CONSTRUCT { \n" +
    "?cls ?cp ?co . \n" +
   " ?prop ?pp ?po . \n" +
"}" +
"WHERE { \n" +
    "?cls a rdfs:Class . \n" + 
    "?cls ?cp ?co .  \n" +
    "?prop a rdf:Property . \n" +
    "?prop ?pp ?po .  \n " + 
"}";

results = qe.execSelect();
```

THe query is in string variable QUERY.
I am using jena 
THe Whole thing is in a interface that has 2 buttons.
QUERY takes a select query when users click button1 and the above query if user clicks button2

**GEtting the following exception if QUERY contains both construct and select**
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecException: Attempt to have ResultSet from a CONSTRUCT query
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.QueryExecutionBase.execSelect(QueryExecutionBase.java:93)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CONSTRUCT` queries result in a model, not a result set. You need to use:

```
Model model = qe.execConstruct();
```

You can't have a query that "contains both construct and select". (unless you mean a construct containing a sub-select?)

You might find the following useful:

```
Query q = QueryFactory.create(QUERY);

if (q.isSelectType()) { ... execSelect, deal with results ... }
else if (q.isConstructType()) { ... execConstruct, deal with result model ... }
else { ... do you deal with DESCRIBE? ... }
```